# mongodb (node) update with upsert syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using the node mongodb module MongoClient method.

My mongodb collection includes records structured like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("546d64103e53563b506433df"), 
    "type" : "staticCollection", 
    "features" : [ 
        { 
            "type" : "static", 
            "properties" : { 
                "source" : "sometext", 
                "timestamp" : "1416455167", 
                "id" : "47759600", 
                "msgType" : 54, 
                "name" : null, 
                "data" : "some data string" 
            }
        } 
    ] 
}
```

When I receive data where the "id" item already exists I want to update all of the items contained within "properties".

When no "id" match exists, I want to insert the entire record.

I'd like to use update with upsert to do this.

I'm struggling to understand what the syntax of the db.collection.update command should be.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/#up._S_setOnInsert). Assuming you're wanting to set the ENTIRE document if the features item isn't found, it would look like this:

```js
var propertiesId = req.query.propertiesId; // or however you're getting it
var allProperties = {} ; //set the full properties from the request etc
db.collection.update(
  { features : { $elemMatch: { 'properties.id' : propertiesId } } },
  { $set : { 'features.$.properties': allProperties },
    $setOnInsert: { 
        type: "staticCollection",
        features: [ { type: "static", properties: allProperties } ]
    }
  },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Will, looks promising.  But when I run this I get an error:    { [MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: features.$.properties]
  name: 'MongoError',
  code: 16836,
  err: 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: features.$.properties' }

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the collection name is: `features`. You can try this:

`db.features.update({"_id" : ObjectId("546d64103e53563b506433df")},
    {
        "type" : "staticCollection", 
        "features" : [ 
            { 
                "type" : "static", 
                "properties" : { 
                    "source" : "sometext", 
                    "timestamp" : "1416455167", 
                    "id" : "47759600", 
                    "msgType" : 54, 
                    "name" : null, 
                    "data" : "some data string 2" 
                }
            } 
        ] 
    }, true)`

All this should be on one line, I put them on many lines to make it easy to read.
The `true` at end of the query indicate that this is an `upsert`.